Setting Rails config.cache_classes=false causes env['warden'].user to fail
I'm running into an issue where setting config.cache_classes=false in my development.rb causes the following method find_verified_user to not get executed.
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.id
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end



Is the whole find_verified_user method not called, like wrote in content? Or is there an error when it is called, like you wrote in the title? And if there is an error, what exactly is the error message, and what does the stacktrace look like?

did you connect to WebSocket channel from Browser and subscribed to any channel ? (how to do this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#client-side-components )

That's a very confusing way of writing env['warden'].user || reject_unauthorized_connection. Avoid assigning local variables in conditions as it leads to the confusion you can see in the misguided answer.

Updated:
Thanks @max for the suggestion.
You can modify your condition code into this:
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      verified_user = env['warden'].user
      if verified_user
        self.current_user = verified_user
        logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.id
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end


You haven't actually understood the code. The assignment in the conditional is kind of smelly and what it actually boils down to is env['warden'].user || reject_unauthorized_connection. That's why assignment in conditionals should be avoided.

Thank you @max for your information. I will revise the code.

It's still kind of unsure if it answers the question or is just a refactor but that's really more of the askers fault than yours. It's missing an actually reproducable example and the asker has not responded to follow questions.

Yes, it. We can wait for it. Thanks.
